# Why does the constructor in C++ behave differently when we include variable types while declaring it?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

So I created a constructor on a class Point.

**Class**

```
class Point {
public:
    Point(); //declare default constructor
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

**Constructor**

```
Point::Point()  {
  x=0.0;
  y=0.0;
}
```

Now, when I print the default values of x and y in main, they show as 0 and 0, which I expect.

However, just for fun, the changed the declaration of the constructor to the following -

**New Constructor declaration**

```
Point::Point()  {
  double x=0.0;
  double y=0.0;
}
```

Now, when I called the same constructor, I got the value of x and y as 2.16703e-314 and 6.95313e-310 respectively. Now, I know the purpose of a constructor. What I wanted to know was what happens when I add the variable type to x and y when I declare a constructor that it starts to behave like that? Hope the question is clear. Happy to clarify if it isn't.

Comment: Your `double x` is now a local variable being set to `0.0`, not the member variable, meaning the member variable (`this->x`) is never explicitly initialised.

Comment: Your second example only initializes local variables instead of the member variaböls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first case

```
Point::Point() {
  x=0.0;  // refers to class member variable x 
  y=0.0;  // refers to class member variable y
}
```

The second case

```
Point::Point()  {
  double x=0.0; //Creating local variable with same name as class member variable
  double y=0.0; //Creating local variable with same name as class member variable
}
```

The comments explains what is happening in each case.
So, in the second case when you are trying to access class member variable you are getting junk value as you are creating a local variable with the same name as the class member variable (different memory location compared to class member variable).

Answer (score 5):

In C++ you are allowed to "shadow" variables.  When you "shadow" a variable, you create a new one with the same name as one in an "outer" scope.  Now the name refers to the inner variable, and any changes are not reflected in the outer one.

Compilers with decent warning settings will tell you when you do this.

```
Point::Point()  {
  double x=0.0;
  double y=0.0;
}
```

here, `x` and `y` are shadowing the `Point::x` and `Point::y` member variables.  So `x=0.0` does not change the `x` in `Point`.